How do I get the section title within a chapter in the report document class to be on the same page as the chapter title?
I am writing a report about my research data so far and am using the report document class. I've made each part of my report a different chapter and to make it more manageable I have created a different .tex file for each chapter and am using \include{} to add the chapter .tex files into the main .tex file. When I add a section into a chapter, it puts the section title on a new page in the main .tex file, leaving the chapter title orphaned on a page by itself. How do I get it so the section title is just below the chapter title? Code included below
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\normalfont
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm,}



\begin{document}

\title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\author{XXX}
\date{July 2024}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Abstract}
Insert abstract text here!

\chapter{Introduction}
Insert introduction text here!

\chapter{Methods}
Insert methods text here!

\chapter{Results}
\include{Results/Results}

\chapter{Discussion}
Insert discussion text here!

\chapter{References}
Insert references here!

\chapter{Plan}
Insert 12 month plan here!

\end{document}

Results file code:
\section{Bioinformatic Analysis}
\subsection{BLAST Analysis}

The BLAST tool was used to search for related proteins to each query sequence...


Try with \input

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It would work with \include, but OP would need to read that duplicate fairly closely to see how.

tl;dr: Move the \chapter macro inside the \included file.
\include starts and ends with a page break.  The idea is that when you have a several hundred page book, you can have \includeonly{chapters,under,development} in your preamble and LaTeX will only \include those three chapters but with the counters correct.  Then your compilation will go much more quickly.
But in order to have the counters correct (especially the page numbers), LaTeX needs to know where the page breaks will be.  It solves this problem by always having a page break before and after the included material.  Since there is also a page break before \chapter and \part, the intended use case is that the included material is a complete chapter or part.  But if you move the chapter or part title out of the included material, then you get the extra page break.
